# Is there a simple flag to prevent installing X and anything that depends on it via ports?

Tags: freebsd, bsd-ports, x11, headless

I'm running FreeBSD in a small VMWare image and I want to keep it headless. Is there a setting someplace that will guarantee I never pull in X as a dependency, or will I have to rely solely on eternal vigilance? Thanks.

See also: [the same basic question on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/questions/203303/how-do-i-prevent-accidentally-building-x-as-a-dependency-when-installing-a-port)

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka Do you happen to remember what that is?

Comment: Ups. Sorry for deleting - I posted what I found as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include `-DWITHOUT_X11` as make argument. Depending on how you install ports you can 'include' it (sorry - I cannot find the details right now).

Alternatively there is a [ports-mgmt/portconf](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/ports-mgmt/portconf/) package in which you can specify WITHOUT_X11, if I understand correctly, in such manner:

```
*: WITHOUT_X11
```

Please note that it will work only with optional X11 dependencies - installing KDE will still install X11.

Answer (score 2):

According to [the mailing list](http://lists.freebsd.org/pipermail/freebsd-bugs/2004-July/007813.html), you should set `WITHOUT_X11=yes` in `/etc/make.conf`.